# Color PHP variable in html

Tags: php, html

I have this html code with php variable the text will be display in color black but I don't know how to make the variable to be in color red

here is the code

```
<br>Your Intrest Rate is: ".$interest_rate."%\n<br>
```

when I do

```
<br>Your Intrest Rate is: ".<a color=red>$interest_rate</a>."%\n<br>
```

the page stops working

How can I do this please advise?

Comment: It depends. What's your full PHP code? You cannot add variables directly into html code and expect them to proccess without PHP tags.

Comment: What is the point of using an `<a>` tag just to change the text color? `<a>` is for "anchors" (i.e. hyperlinks). Use `<span>` and combine that with CSS to accomplish what you want.

Comment: HTML goes with HTML. You're trying to parse it as PHP, so you get errors because of it. Should be something like `...Rate is: <a color=red>".$interest_rate."</a>%\n<br>`

Comment: You seem to be somewhat randomly piecing together HTML and PHP syntax.  The two are very different things.  It would probably be a good idea to walk through some introductory PHP tutorials.  Copying/pasting things you find on the internet without understanding the tools you're using isn't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell the server to parse the PHP code as PHP code, using PHP tags:

```
<br>Your Interest Rate is: <a style='color:red;'><?php echo $interest_rate; ?>%</a><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see PHP tags or PHP code, but assuming this is a string inside PHP tags (since there is no problem without the anchor tag), your problem is the HTML tags outside the string.

Do this:

```
<br>Your Intrest Rate is: <span style='color:red'>".$interest_rate."%</span><br>
```

Comment: it perfectly work. so basically when I have a variable I can not use a <a tag I have to use <span tags?

Comment: No, you can use `<a` tags, but they are for links. `<span` is better when you just want to style a particular element.

Comment: thanks a lot but now I am running into another problem see when I try <br>Your Intrest Rate is: <span align='right'>".$interest_rate."%</span><br> I am trying to align the variable right its still not working

Comment: You must do those things with style parameters. Take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Comment: print("<p>Your monthly income is: $<span style='text-align:right;'>".$monthlyincome1."</span>\n");      I used it exactly how they said it is not working

Comment: The styling will depend on many factors. In your case, probably missing a parent div with a set width. You could do a tutorial on css on codeacademy, you'll learn quick and will surely master the element styling.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
<br>Your Intrest Rate is: ".<a color=red>$interest_rate</a>."%\n<br>
```

to this if your outside a php tag:

```
<br>Your Intrest Rate is: ".<a color=red><?php $interest_rate ?></a>."%\n<br>
```

and if your inside a php tag:

```
<br>Your Intrest Rate is: ".<a color=red>".$interest_rate."</a>."%\n<br>
```

**and be sure that the variable('$interest_rate') isset**

Comment: If inside php, then maybe just: `<br>Your Interest Rate is: <a color=red>".$interest_rate."</a>%\n<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Provided your actually able to view the `$interest_rate` variable, you should use a `<span>` or something similar to get your text to appear red.

`<br>Your Intrest Rate is: ".<span style="color: #ff0000;"><?php echo $interest_rate; ?></span>."%\n<br>`

Comment: the variable is still not right... he has to use `<?php echo $interest_rate; ?>`

Comment: Apologies, I've amended my answer to include that. (Completely forgot how to php today)

Comment: @Blueblazer172 not necessarily. OP probably just posted the inner string content and this is inside php tags already.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes yeah but then he has tu use dots before and after the value

Comment: OP's original code does this. He just added the tags outside the string, that's the main problem.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 only if he is echoing the entire string.

Comment: @Kieran jeah but this is not seeable. he hasn't posted php code. so we dont know